# Generator Charger Grounding

Tags: power-electronics, grounding, solar-charge-controller, power-generation, windturbine

A while back I sketched up a small charge control circuit that can be used with either a wind or solar generator scenario.

This is only meant for smaller 12V 10-30W /hobbyist/home made generators and not something commercial. I built a generator from an old ceiling fan and have a solar panel lying around...if I'm getting a board made mind as well do two in one!

I have this on a perfboard (working-ish) but I know there are improvements to be made.

And finally the question:

There is a small section in the center-ish of the schematic where windGND, solarGND, and GND meet.
Is this correct or should the Ground planes be kept separate and connect only at voltage regulator/MOSFET points?
--> I read something about star configured grounding planes but I didn't exactly understand where to use them or if they were indeed necessary

**Also, if you have ANY suggestions, id be happy to hear them!
My experience is in software but hardware is just fun!**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ground is a symbol you call 0V , while any losses to and from ground will alter analog levels slightly according to the ground resistance and wire inductance.  This is important when considering noise influence on analog signals and high speed logic. But here most levels are slow and logic levels and power losses are probably negligible by you choice of twisted power cables.

You can switch the grounds with Nch with a solid common 12V reference or as done with Pch and a solid gnd.

Star grounds are useful when you want to avoid current shared voltage drops from accumulating.